# Multiple frequent system log entries from CreareSeo module

Tags: magento-1.8, system.log

We're seeing frequent (every minute) entries in system.log like this:

```
2017-05-26T08:48:22+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /chroot/home/<domain>/html/app/code/community/Creare/CreareSeoCore/Model/Observer.php on line 272
2017-05-26T08:48:22+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /chroot/home/<domain>/html/app/code/community/Creare/CreareSeoCore/Model/Observer.php on line 279
2017-05-26T08:48:22+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /chroot/home/<domain>/html/app/code/community/Creare/CreareSeoCore/Model/Observer.php on line 279
```

The relevant section of observer.php is:

```
public function getTitle()
{
    $pagetype = $this->metaHelper()->getPageType(); 
    if ($pagetype && $pagetype->_code != "cms")
    {
        if (!$pagetype->_model->getMetaTitle())
        {
            $this->_data['title'] = $this->setConfigTitle($pagetype->_code);
        } else {
            $this->_data['title'] = $pagetype->_model->getMetaTitle();
        }
    } else if($pagetype->_code == "cms"){       // line 272
        $this->_data['title'] = $pagetype->_model->getTitle();
    }

    if (empty($this->_data['title'])) {

        // check if it's a category or product and default to name.
        if($pagetype->_code == "category" || $pagetype->_code == "product"){    //line 279
            $this->_data['title'] = $pagetype->_model->getName();
        } else {
            $this->_data['title'] = $this->getDefaultTitle();
        }
    }



    return htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode(trim($this->_data['title']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
}
```

Any ideas what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting errors because the code is trying to get properties of an object even if its not set.
Above code should look something like this.

```
public function getTitle()
{
    $pagetype = $this->metaHelper()->getPageType(); 
    if ($pagetype && $pagetype->_code != "cms")
    {
        if (!$pagetype->_model->getMetaTitle())
        {
            $this->_data['title'] = $this->setConfigTitle($pagetype->_code);
        } else {
            $this->_data['title'] = $pagetype->_model->getMetaTitle();
        }
    } else if($pagetype && $pagetype->_code == "cms"){       // line 272 // Added condition to check if $pagetype is set
        $this->_data['title'] = $pagetype->_model->getTitle();
    }

    if (empty($this->_data['title'])) {

        // check if it's a category or product and default to name.
        if($pagetype && ($pagetype->_code == "category" || $pagetype->_code == "product")){    //line 279 // Added condition to check if $pagetype is set
            $this->_data['title'] = $pagetype->_model->getName();
        } else {
            $this->_data['title'] = $this->getDefaultTitle();
        }
    }

    return htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode(trim($this->_data['title']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
}
```